# Momentjs Calendar with Seconds

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I'm using the Moment.js library for some time operations in a project.

I currently use the `calendar` function, which returns information like "Today at 6:28 PM" or "last Sunday at 6:42 PM".

I now have a need for second-accurate information, like "Today at 6:28:39 PM" or "last Sunday at 6:42:55 PM".  Is there any built-in way to do this in the Moment.js library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Moment is highly customizable](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/). In this case you want to format the LT entry, since the calendar object uses that:

```
moment. locale('en', {
    calendar : {
        lastDay : '[Yesterday at] LT',
        sameDay : '[Today at] LT',
        nextDay : '[Tomorrow at] LT',
        lastWeek : '[last] dddd [at] LT',
        nextWeek : 'dddd [at] LT',
        sameElse : 'L'
    }
});
```

Before altering it:

```
moment().subtract('days', 2).calendar()
"last Wednesday at 3:44 PM"
```

So now you need to customize the LT:

```
moment.locale('en', {
    longDateFormat : {
        LT: "h:mm:ss A", // <----------- add :ss
        L: "MM/DD/YYYY",
        l: "M/D/YYYY",
        LL: "MMMM Do YYYY",
        ll: "MMM D YYYY",
        LLL: "MMMM Do YYYY LT",
        lll: "MMM D YYYY LT",
        LLLL: "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY LT",
        llll: "ddd, MMM D YYYY LT"
    }
});
```

And now you get seconds in your time:

```
moment().subtract('days', 2).calendar()
"last Wednesday at 3:41:05 PM"
```

Comment: moment.lang is now deprecated. Use moment.updateLocale instead

Answer (score 2):

You can alter Moment's long date formats to include seconds.  [By default](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/), the `calendar` function uses the `LT` format, which is initially set to `"h:mm a"` (time to minutes plus AM/PM).  You can [alter](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/long-date-formats/) the `LT` format to include [seconds](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) (`"h:mm:ss A"`) as follows:

```
moment.lang('en', {
    longDateFormat : {
        LT: "h:mm:ss A",
        L: "MM/DD/YYYY",
        l: "M/D/YYYY",
        LL: "MMMM Do YYYY",
        ll: "MMM D YYYY",
        LLL: "MMMM Do YYYY LT",
        lll: "MMM D YYYY LT",
        LLLL: "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY LT",
        llll: "ddd, MMM D YYYY LT"
    }
});
```

[More details here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/long-date-formats/).

Answer (score 0):

You can combine predefined formats, e.g.

```
format("LL LTS")
```